# Get value of VARIANT to int

Tags: c++, com, variant

I access with my program a COM object (in my example CANoe) and call a method get_Value to get the value of a variable in the COM object. The pointer pVariable is a pointer to the COM object of the variable:

```
 VARIANT variable; 
 result = pVariable->get_Value(&variable);
```

To work with the value in c++ I want to save the value in the VARIANT variable in an integer variable. How can I cast the value in the VARIANT variable to an integer variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of variant access macros in **OleAuto.h**. When you have get the value, you should ensure that it has the correct type. Then you can read it:

```
int value;

if (V_VT(variable) == VT_INT)
{
    value = V_INT(variable);
}
```

There are several integer types defined for variants. Please look at **wtypes.h** and check what actual type is stored in your current variant object and use the appropriate V_xxx macro.

Comment: Although VT_INT does exist (for platform-dependent 32/64 integer), VT_I4 is much more common, and likely to be used in this case. You can also use the VariantChangeType Windows API to coalesce into the requested vartype.

Answer (score 5):

Just access the variant value after you made sure you got a proper integer value.  Like this:

```
 VARIANT variable; 
 HRESULT hr = pVariable->get_Value(&variable);
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) hr = VariantChangeType(&variable, &variable, 0, VT_I4);
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) this->Yadayada = variable.lVal;
 else ReportFailure(hr);
```

Comment: Should be HRESULT hr = pVariable->get_... and hr = VariantChangeType. Otherwise SUCCEEDED(hr) doesn't make sense.

Comment: The power of muscle memory.  Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant Hello and thank you for your answer. I get the error message that VT_INT4 was not declared. So I tried it with VT_INT... What do you mean with Yadayada? My class has no member named Yadayada... And of what variable type is result? I use the MinGW compiler of Qt

Comment: Fixed.  Yadayada is whatever variable you want to assign, I don't know what name you use since you didn't post enough code.

Comment: Why should la-ga change the type with the `VariantChangeType`?

Comment: @harper - Because there's no requirement for client code to actually pass a variant of the *exact* type.  The nature of variants.  If it wants to pass a VT_I1 or VT_I2 then that's just fine, it is still convertible to an *int*.  Or a VT_BSTR, a scripting or VB programmer expects that work.  It does with VariantChangeType().

Comment: the second `&variable` should be `&result` no?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what variant type you are talking about. For example, a variant holding a date value will likely fail if you try to convert to an integer.

```
HRESULT hr = VariantChangeType (&VariantDest, &VariantSource, 0, VT_I4);
long t = VariantSource.lVal;
```

Don't forget to check the HRESULT value.